# How do I change the delta values using a hook?

Tags: views, hooks

I have a view getting all fields from nodes that have a relationship with the viewed node (using delta = all); it then only shows one node using CSS styles.

How do I change the delta value for every request and take its value as an argument from the URL?

I reloaded the page from JavaScript when the user needs to see the next field (using pager controls).

Which hooks does the Views module provide to edit that value?

Comment: Just to make sure. The argument already exist in the url and you only need to take it and change the delta option, right?

Comment: yes the pager controls links to related nodes of the viewed one 

I need to make the delta like a contextual filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the validation criteria with PHP code in your contextual filter settings:

**When the filter value IS in the URL or a default is provided**

Specify validation criteria -> PHP Code

```
if($handler->argument){
  $view->display['default']->handler->options['pager']['options'] = array(
    'offset' => 0, 
    'items_per_page' => $handler->argument
  );
  return true;
}
else {
  return false;
}
```

That's it. Now, for every request the delta will be equal with the argument from the URL.
`$handler->argument` It's the argument which has been provided by your contextual filter.

Comment: where to put that piece of code

Comment: In your contextual filter settings. I updated my answer.