# Why do I get the following error?

Tags: views, hooks

I need to implement `hook_views_query_alter()` to change the value of delta of the field that form a relationship.

As I posted in [change delta value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77680/change-delta-values/77853), the code is the following one.

```
   function supermama_misc_views_query_alter($view, $query) {
     $view->$query->table_queue['field']['join']->extra[2]['value'] = 1;
   }
```

It gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property

The same error appears if I use the following code.

```
    function supermama_misc_views_post_build($view) {
      if ($view->name == 'gallery_images') {
        $view->$query->table_queue['field']['join']->extra[2]['value'] = 1;
      }
    }
```

What's wrong with the code? How do I bypass the error?

Comment: Please `dpr()` or `var_dump` problematic variable. Knowing what's in `$view` and in `$query` will tell us what's empty - and knowing what is empty is a key to tell how to make it full or to substitute it.

Comment: the field is already has a value
    $view->$query->table_queue['field']['join']->extra[2]['value']
ans all parents also print_r() shows the contents of (objects and arrays ...etc)

Comment: If you will not share their content with us, there is hardly anything we can do with it. If property is not, in fact, empty but PHP says it is, it would be a PHP bug. But somehow I can't believe it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot [molot](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/16495/molot)

the problem was a wrong implementation to the views hooks as [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/how-do-i-use-hook-views-query-alter?rq=1)

and [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)

This hook should be placed in MODULENAME.views.inc and it will be auto-loaded. MODULENAME.views.inc must be in the directory specified by the 'path' key returned by MODULENAME_views_api(), or the same directory as the .module file, if 'path' is unspecified.