# In Drupal 7 Views Contextual Filters, is there a way to manipulate the URL Value via PHP?

Tags: 7, views

Given that **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL** has a default value option of PHP to manipulate arguments. (Keep in mind this is when there is **NO** value set. In my case a value is always set, so this option will always be ignored.)

Is there a PHP option to manipulate **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS IN THE URL OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED**? The only option available is validation. I need a PHP option so I can manipulate the argument that is passed in. How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: You *should* be able to change the argument by selecting PHP as the **validator** and then changing `$handler->argument` there.

Comment: The validation option is exactly what you're looking for. Here is an example how to use the `$handler->argument` within PHP validation code [set-delta-value](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77680/how-do-i-change-the-delta-values-using-a-hook/77853#77853)